# selecting words that only have specific letters in them

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to print only words that match the regex I provide and only contain the letters provided in the second parameter. The regex works perfectly, but the letter selection does not.

```
import re

def search(regex,letters):
    letters=set(letters)
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    for word in content:
        word=word.strip()
        if(pattern.findall(word)):
            if letters & set(word):
                print(word)


#search(r'^(n|u|p|g|o|u|e|b|l){6}$')
#search(r'^t(i|a)[a-z]{3}')
content=["hello","helps","halts","random"]
search(r'^h(e|a)[a-z]{3}','hltsa') #returns: hello,helps,halts
```

My goal is to get this to return only halts, because it matches the second parameter.

Comment: What does `if letters & set(word):` suppose to check ?

Comment: I found that in this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443302/search-strings-in-list-containing-specific-letters-in-random-order">SO post</a> I thought it would check to see if a word contained those letters

Comment: Try to print `set(word)` and then try to print `letters` and finally print `letters & set(word)` and see what it gives you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

def search(regex,letters):
    letters=set(letters)
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    for word in content:
        word=word.strip()
        if(pattern.findall(word)):
            if set(word) >= letters:
                print(word)


#search(r'^(n|u|p|g|o|u|e|b|l){6}$')
#search(r'^t(i|a)[a-z]{3}')
content=["hello","helps","halts","random"]
search(r'^h(e|a)[a-z]{3}','hltsa') #returns: hello,helps,halts
```

try this, I only changed `if letters & set(word):`

in documentation for sets you can find this

```
s.issubset(t)    s <= t  test whether every element in s is in t
s.issuperset(t)  s >= t  test whether every element in t is in s
```